# How to access sub-elements by tag in Backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm totally new to Backbone and JS so forgive me if this is a silly question.

Here is my HTML code:

```
  <div id="sectionOne">
        <h3 class="listHeader"></h3> 
        <ul></ul>
    </div>

    <div id="sectionTwo">
        <h3 class="listHeader"></h3> 
        <ul></ul>
    </div>

    <div id="sectionThree">
        <h3 class="listHeader"></h3> 
        <ul></ul>
    </div>
```

If I have a Backbone view where the id refers to sectionOne, for instance, right now I am doing:

```
$(this.id).append(someCode);
```

Which works, but of course it only prints within the div. How can I append the code directly to the h3 and ul elements? I tried

```
$(this.id.ul).append(someCode);
```

and

```
$(this.ul).append(someCode);
```

but neither works. I found a lot of similar questions on here but nothing on how to access elements by tag name within a certain ID.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more specifically a jQuery selector question.

`$(this.id + ' ul')` will select ul elements nested inside of the div.

`$(this.id + ' h3')` will select h3 elements nested inside of the div.

Comment: Yes, now that I think about it this is more of a general jQuery issue, my bad. Either way, tried this out and program is working perfectly now :) Thanks!